# Is there a website or other resource that list trains with sleeping car?

Tags: trains, online-resources, night-transport

Traveling by train by itself is an experience, and sleeping on one can be part of that experience. I would like to know if there is a website or other reosource that list trains with [sleeping car](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_car).

Doesn't need to be fancy luxorious trains.

I am interested in Europe but if a resource exists with more regions that would be a plus.

Comment: Which region are you interested in? I doubt there is any world-wide database of such trains, so it will need to be narrowed to a specific region.

Comment: seat61 isn't good enough?

Comment: @MarkMayo I have no idea. I will check it.

Comment: @MarkMayo. Thanks for the tip. It's a good resource, with lots information but not so good organization. At least for what I am looking for.

Comment: Yeah I've thought about doing a similar site, but organising all that is hard - do you do it by route, or country, or class etc.  Wealth of info though!  Should I put it as an answer, or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @MarkMayo I definitly consider it a possible answer. The fact that isn't exactly what I expect does not make it less valuable as an information source relating this subject.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the website [The Man in Seat 61](http://seat61.com/).

He's tried to put together an incredible wealth of information on train travel, the options, routes, and facilities of different journeys around the world.

I used it for European travel, a trip last year across America, and for planning of my Russia travels as well.  Very handy reference resource!

Answer (score 4):

The best online listing of sleeper trains I know of is RailDude.
For example the Germany page http://www.raildude.com/en/germany/country/de lists all the night trains available passing through Germany, you can click on one to see the timetable, type of accomodation, prices etc.

seat61 has a lot of info but it's more of a guidebook than a listing of trains, and is focused on getting from the UK to places rather then getting around Europe.

Another option is to purchase a copy of the European Rail Timetable(search google for 'European Rail Timetable')

Finally, for checking specific routes go to http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query2.exe/en and just search the route(the site is run by Deutsche Bahn but covers most of Europe), giving a departure time in the evening. Sleeper trains will come up as EN(Euronight), CNL(CityNightLine) or D in the Product Column